# Chromebook Lego Mindstorms EV3 trouble

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I want to make a crane in LEGO Mindstorms EV3 and I've already downloaded the software but as you can see below some coding pieces here are not in the Chromebook version.

Should I download the software on a Microsoft computer or can I work around [this issue](https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-program-descriptions/ev3-program-description-robotarm-621fa90f70727e1fa8b5e82a9bdb3446.pdf).

Comment: what coding blocks are not in the chrome version?

Answer (score 1):

LEGO EV3 Classroom from LEGO Education is [available on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.education.ev3classroom).

This is an Android app, but newer Chromebooks have the ability to run Android apps.

This app contains pre-made programs for the four base models: puppy, robotic arm, gyro boy and color sorter.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that certain coding blocks cannot be seen on certain devices (esp. mobile) is usual. Most people, including me, do not understand why these blocks are not shown on these devices. I believe that some of these missing blocks are the following:

•Loop Interrupt

•Custom My Blocks

•Messaging Block

•Timer

•NXT Sound Sensor

•And way more.

Because of this, you can only make simple programs on these devices. Trying to make the Mindstorms software think you're on a desktop when you're really on an iPhone would probably be too sophisticated for an average person. I can show you the screenshots of how limited you are to programming on my tablet, too:

https://pasteboard.co/J2khG1i.png

https://pasteboard.co/J2khY6Q.png

https://pasteboard.co/J2kikuo.png

It seems like Desktops are the only devices that have all the programming blocks.